# How to pass route and post parameters to WebApi2 with route attribute from Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to migrating my Web api code to Web api 2 and kind of unable to understand how to get it working with angular js. I didn't find any example on the net that kind of explained that.

here is my controller code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v2/bids")]
public class BidsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{quoteId:long}/accept")]
    public HttpResponseMessage AcceptShipmentQuote(long quoteId,[FromBody] string data)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, quoteId);
        return response;
    }
}
```

on the angular JS i have the following code:

```
    function acceptQuote(quoteId, data, fnSuccess, fnError) {
        return $resource("/api/v2/Bids/:quoteId/accept", { quoteId: "@quoteId", data: "@data" },
            { "AcceptQuote": { method: "POST", isArray: false } })
            .AcceptQuote(quoteId, data, fnSuccess, fnError);
        }
```

but this is not working as in the fiddler I see that **quoteId** is not getting replaced in the uri and I am sure after I pass that, the next would be to find out that the **data** is not getting in to the method as post.

here is the error I get on fiddler response

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://127.0.0.1:82/api/v2/Bids/accept'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'v2'."}
```

can some one please help me out with the correct way to get this working?

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call to `AcceptQuote()` should be passing the object with parameters (not just the *quotedId* value). As described [in detail here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource), an extract:

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be invoked with the following parameters:
>   - non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
>   ...

so this should work:

```
function acceptQuote(quoteId, data, fnSuccess, fnError) {
  return $resource("/api/v2/Bids/:quoteId/accept", { quoteId: "@id"},
        { "AcceptQuote": { method: "POST", isArray: false } })
        .AcceptQuote({ id : quoteId }, data, fnSuccess, fnError);
```

The first object passed `AcceptQuote()` now contains `parameters` object, which will be searched for a property named `quoteId`, to be injected into the url

To consume any "data", passed as JSON, with ASP.NET Web API, we should/have to create an object/Entity. So if the JSON would be like:

```
{
  "MyProperty1" : "MyValue1",
  "MyProperty2" : "MyValue2",
}
```

Then the C# object:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
   public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

And the Controller action should look like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage AcceptShipmentQuote(long quoteId, MyObject myObject)
{
    var prop1 = myObject.MyProperty1;
    var prop2 = myObject.MyProperty2;
```

Comment: I tried it, but its now generating a wrong uri, its like `http://127.0.0.1:82/api/v2/Bids/accept?quotedId=101`  but i was expecting `http://127.0.0.1:82/api/v2/Bids/101/accept` is that possible?

Comment: I updated my answer. I renamed the `@quotedId` into `@id`. This syntax is there to say Angular: search for a property named `id`. Ths should be then injected in place of `:quoteId`. Please, check the spelling be sure that there is no inocrrectnes in the name. That is the reason, why Angular did not found that parmater and appended that at the end as query string param

Comment: Thanks, had to make one small change, had to change the `/api/v2/Bids/:quoteId/accept` to `/api/v2/Bids/:id/accept` now I see the parameter updated in the uri, however the webapi is still unable to accept the post parameter, not sure where to define that as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'll close this thread and start another one for the Webapi issue as its an altogether different issue in my opinion with passing the simple type in post parameter.

Comment: Angular and Web API ... good choice ;) I've done the same. I would say, you are very close. Just web API is designed to convert data/JSON coming in the request body as an object. This will be deserilaized for us by the framework. We still can step into that process e.g. with some attributes...